# Unity instant simulation of game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for a method of simulating my game till win or lose, to feed into a Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm.

My game is a turn based , tile based tactical RPG similar to Final Fantasty Tactics, Fire Emblem etc.

The idea is that the AI would perform thousands of playouts (or up until a threshold) until they determine the optimal next move.

### The Simulation

Each AI and Player agent would make a random valid move, until the game is over.

**Why a MCTS Simulation? Why not minmax?**

I need to simulate the game as closely to the real thing for several reasons:

1. Encoding the game state into a lower-dimensional structure is impossible as most actions are tightly coupled to Unity constructs like Colliders and Rays.
2. It is fairly difficult, if not impossible to statically evaluate the game state at `X` moves ahead - without any knowledge of previous moves. Therefore I would need to carry out each move sequentially on a game state, to produce the next game state before anything can be evaluated.

To expand on point 2:
Using a simple minmax approach, and statically evaluating the game state by looking at something like the Current Health of all players, would be useful but not accurate.
As not every action will provide an immediate change to health.

**Example:**

Which produces a higher (max damage) dealt over 2 turns:

1. Move infront of player, attack -> Move behind player, attack

OR

2. Move infront of player, Use attack buff -> Attack for x4 damage

In this example, the minmax approach would never result in the 2nd option, even though it does more damage over 2 turns, due to its static evaluation of the buff move resulting in 0, or perhaps even negatively.

In order for it to select the 2nd option, it would need to retain knowledge of previous actions. Ie. it would need to simulate the game almost perfectly.

When we add in other elements like: Stage Traps, destructible environment and status effects. It becomes pretty much impossible to use a static evaluation

### What I've tried

**Time.timeScale**

This allows me to speed up physics and other interactions, which is exactly what I need. *However* - this is a global property, so the game will appear to run at super speed for a fraction of a second when the AI is "thinking".

**Increasing the speed of NavMesh Agents**

All my movements take place on a NavMesh - so the only perceivable way of making these movements "instant" is to increase the speed. This is problematic as the movements are not fast enough - and it causes physics issues due to the increased velocity, sometimes characters spin out of control and fly off the map.

---

For reference here is a screenshot of my (in active development) game.

[image]

### Question

What I need is a method for "playing" my game extremely quickly.

I just need to be able to run these simulations quickly and efficiently before every AI move.

I would love to hear from someone with some experience doing something like this - but any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think realistically you'd have to make a simplified abstract model of the game; one which doesn't involve simulating all aspects of the rendering and gameplay. In terms of the tight coupling of colliders, is that because e.g. the amount of damage depends on player aim in some way? You've probably also got some sort of model that represents the tiles in the world - or is it just the navmesh? As a worst case you could try a headless build; that way you don't have to compute the rendering at least.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Thanks for the reply! I have toyed with this idea many times. The coupling is a result of my implementation of aiming - exactly. Basically a Ray is cast to determine what the character is aiming at. Perhaps I need to re-evaluate my approach here. Thinking about it now - perhaps it would make more sense to use a simple array based representation of the entities. That way I do not need to rely on the Physics engine..... 
Thanks for the input , really considering a big refactor now! lol

Comment: Lol it would be a shame to rewrite a bunch of your combat just to add AI, especially if you're happy with how it works already :) Is the aim off-grid, as in I can click anywhere to fire off an attack which lands there, or is it bound to tiles? I click on tile x,y and the attack happens there, potentially affecting some fixed radius of tiles around it

Comment: True that, it would be a massive refactor as well. I had not built the game with this in mind. To answer your question - everything is aligned to a grid yes. It is not possible to carry out an action that is not snapped to a tile.

Comment: Ok in that case I'd definitely recommend tweaking the way damage amounts are calculated - it sounds like it's something that doesn't need to rely on the physics engine anyway. Let's say I've got an ice attack which is going to affect tile x and the 8 tiles around it. The model of the game has a grid of tiles, so that can be used to select the 9 tiles that are being hit, and in turn, can then provide the list of characters being affected. The model then outputs that characters a, b and c are now frozen for 1 turn. If the game is just a visual of the model then it ends up being accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Build an abstract model of your core mechanics

For something to run quickly, we need it to be simple - that means stripping back the game to its basic mechanics, and representing that (and that only).

So, what does that mean? Well, first we have a tile based world. A simple representation of that is a 2D array of Tile objects, like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This gameworld is 20x20 tiles
/// </summary>
public Tile[,] Tiles = new Tile[20,20];
```

Unreachable parts of the world - e.g. because the room is non-rectangular or there's non-interactive furniture in the way - can simply be null values in this array.

Next, there's characters which move around on these tiles. Each character has health too:

```cs
public class Character {
    /// <summary>
    /// The tile this character is on.
    /// </summary>
    private Tile _currentLocation;

    /// <summary>
    /// The tile this character is on.
    /// </summary>
    public Tile CurrentLocation{
        get{
            return _currentLocation;
        }
        set{
            if(_currentLocation != null)
            {
                _currentLocation.Occupier = null;
            }
            _currentLocation = value;
            _currentLocation.Occupier = this;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Its HP
    /// </summary>
    public float Hitpoints = 100f;

    public void SetLocation(Tile newLocation){
        CurrentLocation = newLocation;
    }

}
```

We could make more specialised variants of Character, like `class Hero : Character` with specialised properties, but we'll ignore that for now.

CurrentLocation above also updates the tile too - for speed it helps to know which character is standing on a particular tile, so here's a tile class with that in mind:

```cs
public class Tile{
    public Character Occupier;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Ok, so let's instance a world - this one is rectangular for simplicity, so all the tiles are populated:

```cs
for(var x=0;x<20;x++){
    for(var y=0;y<20;y++){
        Tiles[x,y] = new Tile(){X = x, Y = y};
    }
}
```

And we'll just slap down 2 characters in a particular location:

```cs
var badGuy = new Character();
badGuy.CurrentLocation = Tiles[3,4];

var hero = new Character();
hero.CurrentLocation = Tiles[9,9];
```

From this point, we have a very simplistic model of the world. We can ask it, for example, what is standing at tile x,y by checking `Tiles[x,y].Occupier`. From here, you start adding your mechanics to the model - that could be, for example, some sort of `aTile.Attack(AttackType.IceBlast)` method:

```cs
public void Attack(AttackType type, Character attackedBy){
    // impacts type.Range tiles around this one, dealing damage to each Occupier.
    // Get a neighbouring tile via e.g. yourReferenceToTheTilesArray[X+1, Y].
}
```

Importantly, the game is then modified to be just a reflection of the model - that way the model is always accurate, as it drives the game and is the true source of, for example, damage amounts. You could add events to it, so when the above Attack method is called, some OnAttack handler gets triggered which then fires off animations when the full game is running.

A model like this can then be run as standalone C# program, completely outside of Unity, with the ability to generate millions of turns per second for testing or AI training purposes.

Comment: If possible to implement in TE's games, this is the solution. In games where such abstraction is not well possible (like 3D FPS for example) even AAA titles struggle at achieving reasonably intelligent AIs.